# Python - Argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I've a file `a.py`. I want to write a command

```
python a.py create b c d e
```

which *creates* the `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` ES index. How can I add `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` into the commandline?

Following is my code:-

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("create", help="Creates index of the given app name.")
if args.create_index:
    pass
```

I get the following error:-

```
a.py: error: too few arguments
```

Comment: Your code fails to compile because `args` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nargs` parameter for your parser, like so

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('indexes', type=str, nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.indexes

➜ python test.py a b c d e
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```